# kinetic.js: stage not getting 'click' event

Tags: kineticjs

I put an event handler on the stage in my application like so:

```
stage.on( 'click', onStageClick );
```

However, my event handler is not getting called.  When I put a click event handler on the canvas that is created by the stage, like so:

```
$( stage.children[ 0 ].canvas._canvas ).on( 'click', onCanvasClick );
```

it *does* get called.

Is there something in between the `stage` and the `canvas` that could be eating the click event?  Or ... what am I doing wrong?

Odd addendum:  If I add an `image` object to the `layer` in the canvas ... then I *do* start getting the `click` event on my `stage`.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `contentClick` as your event.

From the [KineticJS documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html):

> The Kinetic Stage supports contentMouseover, contentMousemove,
>   contentMouseout, contentMousedown, contentMouseup, contentClick,
>   contentDblclick, contentTouchstart, contentTouchmove, contentTouchend,
>   contentTap, and contentDblTap.

Here's a fiddle to demostrate: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/L5MLq/

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the `contentClick` rather than the `click` event:

```
stage.on('contentClick',function(){
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @markE ... that was certainly the fix.  I gave the official answer check-mark to klenwell because he got there slightly before you, but it was great to have the answer confirmed by a second person.

Comment: In fairness, @markE finished a bit before me. I didn't realize he was working on it when I started and I got held up fiddling on the fiddle.

Comment: @klenwell.  It's all good...as long as the question was answered :-)